# Find next birthday that occurs on a specific day in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I got a students table and I need to find , for each student, his next birthday that will occur on a Sunday. How can I do that in Oracle Sql?

Example: Bob, found in table students has his dob '23/10/1994'. The output would be '23/10/2016' because this is the first date(starting from sysdate) that will occour on a Sunday and will also be his birthday.

Comment: Use to_char function with mask 'D' - day of week. And to get few next birthdays you can use hierarchical query or recursive.

Comment: post some sample data

Comment: In your example, input: 23/10/1994. Why not 23/10/2005? It's Sunday

Comment: I think OP wants first date after today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b436c/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Students ( Name, DateOfBirth ) AS
          SELECT 'Alice', DATE '1994-10-22' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Bob',   DATE '1994-10-23'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Carol', DATE '1992-02-29'   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Dates ( Name, DateOfBirth, Birthday, Incr ) AS (
  SELECT Name,
         DateOfBirth,
         ADD_MONTHS( DateOfBirth, ( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE ) - EXTRACT( YEAR FROM DateOfBirth ) ) * 12 ),
         EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE ) - EXTRACT( YEAR FROM DateOfBirth )
  FROM   Students
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Name,
         DateOfBirth,
         ADD_MONTHS( DateOfBirth, ( Incr + 1 ) * 12 ),
         Incr + 1
  FROM   Dates
  WHERE  TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( DateOfBirth, Incr * 12 ), 'DAY' ) <> 'SUNDAY   '
)
SELECT Name, DateOfBirth, Birthday
FROM   Dates
WHERE  TO_CHAR( Birthday, 'DAY' ) = 'SUNDAY   '
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b436c/7/0)**:

```
|  NAME |                DATEOFBIRTH |                   BIRTHDAY |
|-------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|   Bob |  October, 23 1994 00:00:00 |  October, 23 2016 00:00:00 |
| Alice |  October, 22 1994 00:00:00 |  October, 22 2017 00:00:00 |
| Carol | February, 29 1992 00:00:00 | February, 28 2021 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EXTRACT` function with `DAY`.

`nls_territory = 'AMERICA';`

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob) = 7
```

or

`nls_territory = 'UNITED KINGDOM';`

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob) = 6
```

*(Assuming table is called `student` and birthday/date of birth field is called `dob`)*

Comment: Doesn't this return all records from the student table where the birthday is a sunday? It's not exactly what OP asks for.

Comment: Sorry, but I asked something else. Added an example.

Comment: @Rene Question changed after I answered unfortunately! If I could have foreseen that I would also foresee this weekend lotto numbers!

Comment: Original question *(which you edited to correct a spelling mistake)* included `his next birthday that will occour in a Sunday`.  Unfortunately your answer finds `his DoB is on a Sunday`.  These are not the same thing.  I personally was born on a Sunday and so your queries would include me, but my next birthday is not on a Sunday.  That is why I have down voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
--prepare test data
create table students(name varchar2(50), dob date)

insert into students(name, dob)
select 'Student '||rownum, to_date('1970.12.31','yyyy.mm.dd')-rownum from all_objects
 where rownum < 365

--the query
select s.*
,to_char(s.next_dob,'DAY') day_of_week
 from (
select st.*
       ,to_date((extract(YEAR from sysdate) + addyear)*10000+extract(MONTH from dob)*100+extract(DAY from dob),'YYYYMMDD') as next_dob              
from students st
    ,(select rownum -1 as addyear from all_objects where rownum < 9)
)s
where s.next_dob > sysdate
 and rtrim(to_char(s.next_dob,'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
order by next_dob
```

Comment: `TO_DATE( ... 'YYYYMMDD' )` will fail if you are adding years to someone born on 29th February.

Comment: agree... it's better to use smth like this  
    add_months( to_date('15-dec-2000'), 12 )-1

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the birthdate by select statement and save it to new_birthdate.

```
declare


birthdate DATE:= to_date('10-23-1994', 'mm/dd/RRRR');
yr NUMBER;
new_birthdate DATE;
temp DATE;
X BOOLEAN:=FALSE;
BEGIN

new_birthdate := birthdate; --you can remove this and 

 --dbms_output.put_line(temp);
   while (X = FALSE) loop

      new_birthdate:=  to_date(TO_CHAR(add_months(new_birthdate,12), 'MM/DD/RRRR'),'mm/dd/RRRR');
      temp:=new_birthdate;
       dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(TEMP,'DAY'));

       IF TRIM(to_char(temp,'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' AND TEMP > SYSDATE THEN

         X:=TRUE;
       EXIT;
       END IF;
   END loop;
   dbms_output.put_line(TEMP);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
  params AS (SELECT DATE '1994-10-23'  dob
                  , SYSDATE            since_date
                  , 12                 hits
                FROM dual)
SELECT next_dob_date     
  FROM (
        SELECT dob + numtoyminterval(LEVEL, 'YEAR') next_dob_date
          FROM params CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100
       )
 WHERE to_char(next_dob_date, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') = 7
   AND next_dob_date >= (SELECT since_date from params)
   AND rownum <= (SELECT hits from params)
```